# print @ in quotes in perl

Tags: perl, quotes, symbols

I want to print the line:

```
my email is "abc@gmail.com"
```

using a perl script.

Below is a snippet of what I am trying to do:

```
print "my email is \"abc@gmail.com\";
```

However when I run the program is does not recognize the @ symbol.  How do I tweak the code snippet so that I get the @ to display?

Comment: Escape it with `\@` or use single quotes.

Comment: Escaping is needed for perl tries to interpolate a list variable otherwise. Note that your second line of code lacks the terminating double quote.

Comment: print "my email is \"abc\@gmail.com\"";

Comment: @collapsar It's an array variable, not a list variable.

Comment: `print 'my email is "abc@gmail.com"'`

Comment: ***Always*** `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of every Perl program you write.

Comment: @MattJacob What exactly is the difference in perl ?

Comment: @collapsar A list is an ordered collection of scalars, and an array is a variable.

Comment: @collapsar, "Array" is a type of variable, and "list" isn't. List is an ambiguous, overloaded term that means many other things.

Comment: @MattJacob Yes, an 'array' is the variable that holds a 'list' which imho makes it pretty unambiguously a 'list variable'. But you're technically right of course, the precise wording to use is 'array variable'.

Comment: @collapsar: `my @array = (1, 2, 3, 4)`, `my %hash = (1, 2, 3, 4)` and `my $scalar = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]` all "hold lists". So, in Perl, every variable is a "list variable" by your definition. That isn't useful. There is no way that `%hash` or `$scalar` could be said to be "array variables".

Comment: @Borodin The idioms you present are notational shorthands for assignments and do not reflect the datatype of the variable, ie. the way the information is organized and can be retrieved after the assignment. By your reasoning `my %hash = @array` would imply that `%hash` was an array variable.

Comment: @collapsar: `%hash = @array` extracts a *list* of data from the array and assigns it to the hash, so no:  `%hash` is still a "list variable". But the "reasoning" was your own. *"the variable holds a 'list' ... makes it ... a 'list variable'"* A hash *can* hold a list but it *cannot* hold an array. Identifying variables by the type of data they hold is a futile hangover from strongly-typed languages where "string variable" means something. In Perl it does not, and is as uninformative as saying that, in `$n = 2`, `$n` is a "two-variable". A type is named by the way it organises its data.

Comment: @collapsar: Your contention worries me. The most important tenet of software engineering is accuracy, and sloppiness like calling arrays "list variables" is something that is likely to leech into the rest of your work. I can forgive a mistake, but I would not employ someone who vigorously defends their mistakes in the face of much more knowledgeable people.

Comment: @Borodin Whoa, no need get personal. Your SO rep is a strong indication that you are indeed much more knowledgeable. And I appreciate your readiness to share your knowledge (in general and in this thread). However, I do not understand the doggedness with which you pursue your point. Several comments earlier I have acknowledged that the proper term is 'array (variable)' - so the matter is actually settled. All I'm saying is that a hash is a different abstraction than an array and while both may be assigned a list and thus can be said being able to 'hold a list', ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176802/discussion-between-collapsar-and-borodin).

Answer (score 9):

One of the mottos of the Perl community is "there's more than one way to do it".  In this case there are many ways to achieve what you're trying to do, each will have advantages in different situations.  I've illustrated some answers below.

Firstly, you didn't mention what output you were getting.  Assuming you have some sensible default boilerplate like this at the top of your script ...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.012;
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
```

then this line of code ...

```
print "my email is \"abc@gmail.com\"\n";
```

should give you an error message similar to this:

```
Possible unintended interpolation of @gmail in string at ./ptst.pl line 10.
Global symbol "@gmail" requires explicit package name at ./ptst.pl line 10.
Execution of ./ptst.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Which is telling you that Perl is interpreting the `@` symbol to be the start of an array name.  So it takes the 'word' which follows and uses that as an identifier name and thinks you're trying to refer to the array variable `@gmail`.  Since the script does not declare that array with `my @gmail` anywhere, `use strict` will throw a fatal exception. (Note: I tweaked your code a little to include `\n` to add a newline at the end).

The simplest change you could make is to just put a backslash (`\`) in front of the `@` symbol to 'escape' it - i.e.: `\@` tells Perl that you just want an `@` character and this it is not the start of an array identifier.

```
print "my email is \"abc\@gmail.com\"\n";
```

This does look a little messy.  One reason is that you have a double quoted string with double quotes in it, so they are also escaped with `\"`.  Another way to represent a double-quoted string is to use the `qq` operator and then choose your own string delimiters.   Here I used curly braces as the delimiters, so the embedded double quotes no longer need to be escaped:

```
print qq{my email is "abc\@gmail.com"\n};
```

However the main reason to use double quotes is to allow variables in you string to be 'interpolated' (i.e.: the variable name will be replaced with the contents of the va    riable).  But your string doesn't include any variables.  So a better fix might be to just use single quotes, which don't do variable interpolation so symbols like `@` and `$` are not special and don't need to be escaped:

```
print 'my email is "abc@gmail.com"', "\n";
```

Unfortunately the other thing that double quotes do is allow you to use special sequences like `\n` for a newline or `\t` for a tab.  In my example I wanted a newline, so I took advantage of the fact that the `print` function accepts a list of arguments and passed it two strings: the first used single quotes to avoid escaping and the second used double quotes to allow escape sequences.  In another context where you had to use a single string, instead of the comma separator, you could use the `.` operator to concatenate the two strings into one:

```
my $message = 'my email is "abc@gmail.com"' . "\n";
```

But if the only reason for using double quotes is to add the newline on the end of the print, then you could instead use the `say` function which is exactly the same as print but it adds a newline on the end:

```
say 'my email is "abc@gmail.com"';
```

If you try this and get an error like `(Do you need to predeclare say?)` then it's because you're missing the boilerplate lines I mentioned at the start.

Your original script didn't use variables, but adding in a variable would be another way to solve your problem:

```
my $email = 'abc@gmail.com';
say qq{my email is "$email"};
```

or:

```
my $email = 'abc@gmail.com';
say "my email is '$email'";
```

Finally, another approach that is sometimes useful is to use `printf` or `sprintf` to plug variables into a 'template' string.  This can be handy for formatting numbers with decimal places, adding leading zeros, padding strings with spaces etc:

```
printf(qq{my email is "%s"\n}, $email);
```

Once again this became a little more complicated due to the newline.  If you don't need it then it's easier to use single quotes around the format string:

```
printf('my email is "%s"', $email);
```

Comment: Cool. But why the `use 5.012;`?

Comment: I could have said `use feature 'say';` to enable the 'new' `say` function, but `use <version>;`  checks that the Perl interpreter is at least the specified version and enables all features in that version (which include `say`).  In this case, any version later than 5.010 would work for this purpose.  5.12 is old enough to be almost everywhere.

Comment: Yes, understood, but your code doesn't really need anything in new features (or does it?), and it keeps the example simpler.Should have made that clearer.

Comment: I was expecting you to get to `say q{my email is abc@gmail.com};`